# Conditions on Limit

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

I have these two conditions:

$$(H_1)~~\lim_{|t|\rightarrow0}\frac{f(t)}{g_1(t)|t|}=0,\,\,\,\, (H_2)~~\lim_{|t|\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(t)}{g_2(t)|t|}=0$$
$$(H_3)~~\lim_{|t|\rightarrow0}\frac{B(t)}{G_1(t)}=0,\,\,\,\, (H_4)~~\lim_{|t|\rightarrow\infty}\frac{B(t)}{G_2(t)}=0$$

such that $$G_i(t)=\int_{0}^{|t|} g_i(s) ds~~\text{and}~~ l\leq \frac{G_i(t)}{g_i(t)|t|}\leq m,~~ m>l>1$$

How can we conclude from these equations that for a given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $C_{\varepsilon}>0$; $$|f(t)t|\leq \varepsilon(G_1(|t|)+G_2(|t|))+C_{\varepsilon} B(|t|)$$

I don't understand how to obtain  $B$ ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Condition $H_{3}$ indicates that $$B(t) \approx |t|G_{1}(t)$$ when $t$ is close to zero and condition $H_{4}$ suggests that $$B(t) \approx \frac{1}{|t|}G_{2}(t)$$ when $|t|$ is very large. Condition $H_{1}$ suggests that $$f(t) \approx g_{1}(t)t^2$$ when $t$ is close to zero and condition $H_{2}$ indicates that $$f(t)\approx Cg_{2}(t)$$ (for some constant $C$) when $|t|$ is very large.

Comment: i don't know how you do this ?

Comment: what we do after that the sum ??? please